# Parse Error PHP Encapsed String in Magento Module

Tags: php, parsing, magento, error-handling, syntax-error

Receiving the following error while trying to register a custom Magento2 module on my local machine:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''DDF_AdminMenu''
>   (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ')' in
>   /Users/petey/Desktop/magento/app/code/DDF/AdminMenu/registration.php
>   on line 5

I can't seem to understand why I'm getting the error.

My code is the following:

```
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'DDF_AdminMenu',
    __DIR__
);
```

Comment: can you clear cache and then check it because It working in my local

Comment: Cleared and flushed cache. It looks like the parse error came because it was a multi line string.

Comment: run following commands 

php bin/magento setup:upgrade 
php bin/magento setup:di:compile

 clear cache and then check it

Comment: I get the error with each command line.

Comment: can you send me full folder?

Comment: Sure thing. What is the best way to do so?

Comment: send me whole folder in my email id "jscatoz@gmail.com"

Answer (score 0):

I know this may seem obvious but it happened to me

Please make sure you add `<?php` at the beginning of the file